# I'm trying to find my father's birth & death certificate in Poland

Tags: birth-records, death-records, poland

My dad was born 1947 in Poland and died in 1997 in Poland. He migrated to the US and became a naturalized US citizen in the 1970s and also served on the polish army but I can't find the town. My parents were also married in Poland in the same town and came back to the US. He had a brother and sister in Poland and married my mother in Poland. I have pictures of their wedding but I don't know who everyone is. I'm trying to get his birth and death records and military records.

Comment: So if I don't read or write polish and I live in the US how do I go about asking the polish embassy in the US to help me?

Comment: I suggest using Google Translate.

Answer (score 2):

For a person living after World War 2, all those documents can be [obtained online, from the state](https://www.gov.pl/web/gov/uzyskaj-odpis-aktu-stanu-cywilnego-urodzenia-malzenstwa-zgonu). However, this requires one to a) read and write Polish b) have an online Polish government identity. You can also apply for those via a post letter, though overseas mail takes quite some time. It's also easier if you do know your father's PESEL (identification number). There's a small fee to pay, around $5.

Other options are

- asking a family member in Poland to apply for those for you (there's a field on the form to authorize someone else to act in your name)
- asking the Polish Embassy/Consulate in the USA for help - this should be a fairly routine thing for them

Regarding military service, it seems like [one can only obtain their own record](https://www.gov.pl/web/gov/uzyskaj-zaswiadczenie-o-przebiegu-sluzby-wojskowej), not for someone else, even a close family member, and archives available currently end at the end of World War 2.

Comment: Once someone has died family mebers can indeed obtain the dead relative's Military Record.